# How to insert a back slash via client to server db MySQL insert

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a web client - I want to ensure all data entered on the web client is saved to the db (safely/cleanly). I have read several posts on and off stackoverflow on this subject but as yet, I've only partially solved my goal. Right now, I use javascript/jquery to apache mysql 5.6. I can safely enter data like <>"'/ but I cannot enter a \ character. It reaches the server, but by the time the data gets to my database, the \ has gone.

What am I doing wrong?

A summary of the web page below:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
</form>
</body>
```

My javascript/jquery environment set similar to the following

```
formdata["summary"]="some text read from form from form";
var jsondata="data="+JSON.stringify(formdata);
$.ajax({ url: "/register.php", type: "GET", dataType: "json", data: jsondata, success: RegistrySuccess, error: RegistryFail });
```

My PHP v5.6 summary:

```
header("content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$jsondata=json_decode( rawurldecode($_REQUEST["data"]) ,true);
```

(I can dump the output of $jsondata to the screen and it will display my client form data - which could include

```
"<b>123</b>" 
"town \ break"
```

I pass $jsondata thru htmlentities()... example output after htmlentities():

```
address='address &lt;b&gt;123&lt;/b&gt;', 
town='town \ break'
```

I then perform a MySQL prepare, then an insert. Everything goes in, except the "\" is missing...

```
$QUERY="INSERT registry5 SET name='name',address='address &lt;b&gt;123&lt;/b&gt;',town='town \ break'";
$stmt = $DB->prepare($QUERY);
$stmt->execute();
```

My table is defined with utf8 charset, InnoDB storage engine.

What am I missing that prevents me from writing a backslash? I thought I had covered my bases by using htmlentities and UTF8 for trouble free data storage. All help appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to [escape the backslash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php), because it has special meaning inside a PHP string.

Comment: I would have thought preparing my query would have escaped the slash for me. Based on your suggestion, I think http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php is the way forward for me.